# Check_jmx query issue

Tags: jmx

When i tried to fetch JMX attribute value for  object like "com.adobe.granite.replication:type=agent,id="publish"" then get the below output.When we add something after comma then it does not able to fetch the attribute value.

[root@MONITOR01 libexec]#  ./check_jmx -U service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://auth01:9000/jmxrmi -O com.adobe.granite.replication:type=agent,id="publish" -A QueueBlocked

JMX CRITICAL - com.adobe.granite.replication:type=agent,id=publish

But when we tried with below object then it works fine.

root@MONITOR01 libexec]# ./check_jmx -U service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://auth01:9000/jmxrmi -O com.adobe.granite:type=Repository -A BackupResult

JMX OK - BackupResult=Backup completed

We observed that when we add anything like ",id-publish" etc etc in the object then its not able to parse and provide the attribute value.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

we got the solution from here [JMX: Read attribute from Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081417/jmx-read-attribute-from-server)

[root@MONITOR01 libexec]# ./check_jmx -U service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://auth01:9000/jmxrmi -O com.adobe.granite.replication:type=agent,id=\"publish\" -A QueueBlocked

JMX OK - QueueBlocked=false